# Angular 4 - material 2 - md datepicker set first day of the week

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2

How to set first day of the week using material 2?

Currently the default is sunday even if I set the locale to hu or anything else..

Comment: Could you share link to the your matherial2, please?

Comment: Using the 2.0.0-beta.7 version

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Found a workaround:

Write this class

```
import {NativeDateAdapter} from '@angular/material';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {

  getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
    return 1;
  }

}
```

Then import to the app.module like:

```
{provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MyDateAdapter},
```

Answer (score 19):

```
constructor(
    private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale('es');
    this.dateAdapter.getFirstDayOfWeek = () => { return 1; }
  }
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Add some explanation of how you got there.

Comment: Finally this is a workaround that worked for me (with @angular/material 10.2.5). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Pretty much the sam answer as Béla but I had to implement the constructor to get it working.

```
import { NativeDateAdapter } from '@angular/material';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@angular/cdk/platform';

@Injectable()
export class SwedishDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
  constructor() {
    super('sv-SE', new Platform());
  }

  getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using angular 6 with the corresponding version of the material.

The solutions above worked however since i was using the moment.js adapter the application stopped working correctly.

Using the code at https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/material-moment-adapter/adapter/moment-date-adapter.ts  and injecting it into the module made the application detect the correct region and set the starting day to monday (mine was pt-pt).

The only change needed was to set the correct moment import.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the following to you app.module.ts:

```
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-GB' }
  ],
```